# Is there any decentralized cloud project compatible with Polkadot's Substrate?

Tags: database, blockchain, computation, substrate

When developing a DApp, one has to put part of the tech on centralized services such as AWS or Google Cloud.

I am wondering if there are any other projects that allow to **decentralize database and computational power** in order to have fully decentralized and unstoppable DApps?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [Tea Project](https://teaproject.org/) since it offers;

- decentralized cloud
- rich and fully decentralized dapps
- trusted computation environment

For instance, IPFS offers decentralized storage but lacks a decentralized compute layer to go with it. Projects like Helium decentralize data transmission but are missing a compute layer to directly run dApps on network data. Tea Project solves the current issues of decentralized cloud ecosystem. You can check the website and the infographics attached below.

[Tea Project Infographics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJkHa.jpg)

Comment: Not only a web host, TEA project also allows developers to use SQL as if they are dealing with a traditional database. But actually, it is a decentralized database and state machine.

Answer (score 0):

Some decentralized solutions are already emerging in order to decentralize databases and computational power.

For instance, [Aleph.im](https://aleph.im/) is a scalability cross-chain project that does exactly that: decentralized database and computation; compatible with Substrate/Polkadot, Ethereum, BinanceChain, and more.

Check out its SDK in [Javascript](https://github.com/aleph-im/aleph-js) and [Python](https://github.com/aleph-im/aleph-client).

Comment: Feel free to open a PR to add this to Awesome Substrate https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate